# Will any 2.4GHz antenna work for WiFi card?

Tags: wireless-networking

I was going to either buy a biquad antenna or a double biquad antenna, but then I came across a 25 dBi Yagi antenna. The literature says it's "For Router," but will this work to plug into a USB WiFi Adapter with a RP-SMA antenna connector on it? I've already bought the USB WiFi Adapter, an N To RP-SMA adapter, and a 3m M to F RP-SMA extension cord.

Comment: Hi Matt, I've taken out the costings and link to ebay to make the question less like a buying recommendation so it won't get jumped on. Hope that's OK.

Comment: As far as I can tell, **any piece of metal** seems to work.  I rigged up a golf club one time.  Didn't extend the range, but it worked. . .

Comment: surfasb.. if it didn't extend the range, what's the point? lol
Linker3000, ok, thanks, if you think it was necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it will work but being a Yagi (design) aerial, it is very directional so you will have to aim at the 'other end' quite carefully as you'll get very little signal radiation or reception to the sides, above, below or behind that antenna. Mind you, that goes for quads and biquads too.

Comment: Ok.  So what do you think, should I go with the Yagi?  It's cheaper than both the biquad and double biquad, and has more dBi gain [25, vs 12 and 14 on the biquads], but, I was thinking maybe I could mount it on a dish, because I read you can get like 30 dBi with that.

Comment: @Matt, what's your goal? Are you trying to set up a long-range outdoor point-to-point link?

Comment: @Spiff.. I want to be able to get wifi from far away.  When I travel especially, it would be great to be able to connect from any store in a parking lot, etc.  Also, I want to be able to get wifi from our library, which is probably a few hundred feet